# Vim autoindent stops indenting multiline array in bash after 20 lines

Tags: vim, indentation

Given this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

_DATABASES=(
        "secretX"
        "secretmin"
        "secretcopyijui"
        "secretcroma"
        "secretdemo"
        "secretdicopy"
        "secretflashcolo"
        "secretmdat"
        "secretneton"
        "secretprintshar"
        "secretrealjet"
        "secretsolumax"
        "secretunicopia"
        "secretworddigit"
        "secretducao"
        "secrette"
        "secrette_app"
        "secretanopecanh"
        "secretx_ead"
        "secretx_site"
        "secretdroppy"
        "secret"
)
```

When i do `gg=G` on vim, then the code be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

_DATABASES=(
        "secretX"
        "secretmin"
        "secretcopyijui"
        "secretcroma"
        "secretdemo"
        "secretdicopy"
        "secretflashcolo"
        "secretmdat"
        "secretneton"
        "secretprintshar"
        "secretrealjet"
        "secretsolumax"
        "secretunicopia"
        "secretworddigit"
        "secretducao"
        "secrette"
        "secrette_app"
        "secretanopecanh"
        "secretx_ead"
        "secretx_site"
"secretdroppy"
"secret"
)
```

Why?

With smaller arrays everything works gracefully, but when it's an array with more than 20 elements, this happens...

Tested with other language(JS, C++, PHP), no similiar behaviour happened.

Info:

Vim 7.4.52

No .vimrc

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`={motion}`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3D) operator can be defined by a number of settings (`'equalprg'`, `'indentexpr'`, `'lisp'`), but when all those are unset, it falls back to using [C indenting](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#C-indenting). This is what is happening here.

C indenting is meant for the C language, and mostly takes its cues on the C curly braces `{ ... }` and identifiers such as `if`, `else`, `while`, etc.

It turns out a lot of this is quite familiar to bash (and many other languages), so this works well a lot of the time.

In C though, parentheses are used to enclose logical expressions, in variable assignments or `if` or `while` statements. Vim wants to format those (so it wants to keep track of the sets of matching parens), but it wants to put some limits into how deep it looks.

As, in C, parens are used on expressions and those are typically short, the default limit for tracking them is 20 lines.

The [`'cinoptions'`] can control a lot of C indenting and it turns out it has an option to control just that. The [`)N`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#cino-%29) option can be used to tweak the line limit for parens expressions.

For instance, to raise it to 100 lines:

```
:set cinoptions=)100
```

(Or to reduce it to 10, use `:set cinoptions=)10`.)

This can explain what is going on and it's possibly a quick hack that can be made into a usable workaround... But the proper solution here is to set [`'indentexpr'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27indentexpr%27) appropriately for the language you're writing. (Remember, C indenting only kicks in when `'indentexpr'` is unset.)

Vim actually ships a plug-in to indent shell scripts, perhaps you just don't have it enabled. Make sure you have this command in your `.vimrc`:

```
filetype indent on
```

And then make sure your shell script is being recognized as type `sh`:

```
:set filetype?
filetype=sh
```

If it isn't, set it (you might need to dig into why that's not happening):

```
:setf sh
```

You can double check that `'indentexpr'` has been set:

```
:set indentexpr?
indentexpr=GetShIndent()
```

With those settings on, `=` will work as you expect on a shell script.